# Drupal Content Updates Not Visible to Public Without Login Attempt

Tags: users

New to Drupal picking up an existing prototype site design from another newbie.

Installed version = 7.28

Whenever I make any updates to contents or even site name and tagline, as Administrator I see the updates listed as "published".

If I log out and reload the web page, it does not display any of my updates, until I click the user login button on the homepage. (The button was part of the existing Homepage design.) It does not matter whether the login attempt authenticated or not, the web page would refresh and the updated content loads and displays correctly. However, without the login attempt, the site content remains at the revision before the last update, same behavior whether browsing in Firefox or IE.

The permissions for viewing contents is enabled for Administrator, Authenticated User, and Anonymous User. The Drupal site seems to treat an unauthenticated log in attempt to be an Anonymous User. What about when the site URL is entered in the browser, and the public is viewing the site? What is the "role" of the viewer of the site before a login attempt is made?

Where is the site content being pulled from to display in browser when the site URL is first loaded?

Where is the site content being pulled from after a login attempt?

Thanks for any help to point me in the right direction to debug this!

Answer (score 1):

> The Drupal site seems to treat an unauthenticated log in attempt to be an Anonymous User

Correct; an anonymous user *is* unauthenticated.

> What is the "role" of the viewer of the site before a login attempt is made?

"anonymous user"

> Where is the site content being pulled from to display in browser when the site URL is first loaded?

Either the database or your cache store.

> Where is the site content being pulled from after a login attempt?

Ditto - database or cache, depending on your setup, whether caches have been primed for the particular cache id, etc.

It sounds like you simply have page caching enabled for anonymous users. Clear Drupal's caches and see if the problem persists.